# PHP-EWS SOAP response is an object - how to get a specific portion?

Tags: php, object, soap, exchangewebservices

I am using this code along with PHP-EWS to create a Calendar Item on an Exchange 2010 mailbox.

```
<?php

include ("ExchangeWebServices.php");
include ("EWS_Exception.php");
include ("EWSType.php");
include ("NTLMSoapClient.php");
include ("NTLMStream.php");
include ("NTLMStream/Exchange.php");
include ("NTLMSoapClient/Exchange.php");

$host = "email.domain.com";
$username = "asdfasdf";
$password = "123";

$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host, $username, $password);

$request->SendMeetingInvitations = 'SendToNone';
$request->SavedItemFolderId->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = 'calendar';
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Subject = 'this is the subject of the email';
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Start = date('c', strtotime('today'));

$request->Items->CalendarItem->End = date('c',  strtotime('today + 1 day'));
$request->Items->CalendarItem->IsAllDayEvent = true;
$request->Items->CalendarItem->LegacyFreeBusyStatus = 'Free';
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Categories->String = $category;
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Body->BodyType = 'Text';
$request->Items->CalendarItem->Body->_ = $body;

$response = $ews->CreateItem($request);

print_r($response);

?>
```

This works fine, the response outputted to the browser is like:

```
stdClass Object ( [ResponseMessages] => stdClass Object ( [CreateItemResponseMessage] => stdClass Object ( [ResponseCode] => NoError [ResponseClass] => Success [Items] => stdClass Object ( [CalendarItem] => stdClass Object ( [ItemId] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => AAASAHJydXVza2FAc3VicmFkLmNvbQBGAAAAAACyAesJgtiMR71+s/kuiAieBwBrnLmGR6RGTakOvWxNjsbfAAAAQwN1AABrnLmGR6RGTakOvWxNjsbfAABcYtppAAA= [ChangeKey] => DwAAABYAAABrnLmGR6RGTakOvWxNjsbfAABcYx9q ) ) ) ) ) )
```

The only piece I want is the 128 character string following `[Id] =>`.  If I convert this object to a string, I can parse the string like this:

```
$var = 'stdClass Object ( [ResponseMessages] => stdClass Object ( [CreateItemResponseMessage] => stdClass Object ( [ResponseCode] => NoError [ResponseClass] => Success [Items] => stdClass Object ( [CalendarItem] => stdClass Object ( [ItemId] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => AAASAHJydXVza2FAc3VicmFkLmNvbQBGAAAAAACyAesJgtiMR71+s/kuiAieBwBrnLmGR6RGTakOvWxNjsbfAAAAQwN1AABrnLmGR6RGTakOvWxNjsbfAABcYtpzAAA= [ChangeKey] => DwAAABYAAABrnLmGR6RGTakOvWxNjsbfAABcYzc4 ) ) ) ) ) )';

$regex_pattern = "/ /";

$matches = preg_split($regex_pattern,$var);

print_r($matches[36]);
```

However, I am having difficulty converting the object into a string.  Also, if the response ever changes slightly I will not get the proper value returned.  What is the best way to look at the Object, and return the value following `[Id] =>`?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do:

```
$id = $response->ResponseMessages->CreateItemResponseMessage->Items->CalendarItem->ItemId->Id;
```

The advantage is that there's no need to cast objects to string, just get what you need the usual way. Another advantage is that even if M$ changes something, the way ID is returned should stay the same for backward compatibility, hence this will work.

When you edit calendar item the response is nearly the same, only difference is the response message type which is UpdateItemResponseMessage